# Firebase To detect whether if the data exist

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi guys so i'm getting like an input from user to check whether if this address is found in the database, so I have got the check working but I want to display if it is not found in the database alert not found but I can't seem to get the "check whether if return from firebase is null" working. Thank you

```
function DB() {

  var database = firebase.database();
  var ref = database.ref('dbData');

  ref.orderByChild('address').equalTo(checkInput).on("value", function(snapshot) {

     nullcheck = snapshot.val();
     console.log(nullcheck);
     console.log(snapshot.val());

       snapshot.forEach(function(data) {

          var info = data.val();

          if( nullcheck === null || nullcheck === "" ){
              //if it is null  
          }
          else{
            //if it is not null
        }
      }); 
   });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check on `snapshot.val()` like:

```
if (!snapshot.val()) {
   console.log('Null');
}
```

Comment: After implementing your suggestions and arranging, it works! Thank you so much sir

Answer (score 0):

There is an exists function on snapshot that will tell you if there is anything in the response which is probably the easiest way to check

```
firebase.database().ref('test').on('value', (snapshot) => {
    if(snapshot.exists()) {
        console.log('I have data')
    }
})
```

If you don't already, id suggest using VS Code and you can discover all the properties very easily with its ItelliSence